# How to identify Ganglion Cysts? What are possible treatment of it?

Tags: treatment, ganglion-cysts

What are the possible cause of Ganglion Cysts? What kind of health problem it can create? What kind of treatment available for it?

Comment: A ganglion is an anatomical structure present in most animals including humans. It is not a medical condition. I voted for closing. If you misspoke, please edit in the actual name of the condition you wanted to know about.

Comment: Yes, mistakenly I have written Ganglion but it must be Ganglion Cysts.